# Decrease vertical space between empty figure and description environment

Tags: floats, captions, description

I am trying to implement a workaround for adding a caption and label to a description environment.
For that I try to force an empty Figure above the description list, but I cannot reduce the vertical space at all. As a result 3cm of white space are between Figure and description which I would like to reduce. Thanks, in advance!

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{Figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Label}
\end{Figure}

\vspace{0cm} %% trying to reduce space between empty figure and below description

\begin{description}
    \item x
    \item y
    \item z
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The purpose of a floating enviornemnt like `figure` (and I assume the `Figure` that you used, but did not show a definition for) is to mark the content as being taken out of the main document flow to be re-inserted later, so there is no sense in which the `\vspace` was between the figure and the list, it was just between whatever was before the list in the main body. (In particular it could be discarded at a page break, even if the figure was re-inserted there.)

A figure does not have to be an image, if you consider the list to be a captioned figure, just place it in the environment with the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]

    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Label}

\begin{description}
    \item[xx] x
    \item[yy] y
    \item[zz] z
\end{description}
\end{figure}

Some text here.


\end{document}
```

Comment: That makes it clear, thanks! Is it possible to prevent a Figure to overflow if the description is too long for one page?